# OrderCloud.io - Change Password issues

Tags: change-password, ordercloud

I'm developing a app where I need to change the password of the logged in user. where I don't need `OrderCloud.PasswordResets()` which will send email to my mail. I need to change the password without triggering email.

I followed below approach but I'm getting error:

```
OrderCloud.Me.Patch({"Password": "1234567889"});
```

**Response:**

> {"Errors":[ {"ErrorCode":"IdExists","Message":"User already
>   exists.","Data":null} , {"ErrorCode":"InvalidRequest","Message":"User
>   already exists.","Data":null} ,
>   {"ErrorCode":"ServerError","Message":"An unknown error has occurred on
>   the server.","Data":null} ]}

**Request URL**:*https://api.ordercloud.io/v1/me*

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Upon further investigation, this error would be thrown if somehow you have users with duplicate usernames under the same organization. If you remove the duplicate usernames and try again, your issue should be resolved.

<s>You should format your request like this, without the quotes on Password:</s>

```
OrderCloud.Me.Patch({Password: "1234567889"});
```